# listing caption with a break line

Tags: listings, captions, line-breaking

Is there an option to break line in an `lstlisting`'s caption? For example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, caption=uppertext\\lowertext)]
```

I've tried with `\\` and some other solutions, but any of them works.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `caption` using a `tabular`. However, also set the *optional* caption (for the `\lstlistoflistings`) *without* the line-breaking `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame = single, 
    caption = {[upper/lower text]%
               \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                 upper text \\
                 lower text \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
               \end{tabular}}
              ]
Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Due to the `frame`, some vertical adjustment is needed (in the form of `\\[.5\normalbaselineskip]`).